# lambda not getting invoked after s3 bucket file upload, no logs generated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I am trying to create my infra and lambda trigger via terraform for aws, where i am creating an s3 bucket and uploading a file to it and then calling a lambda function to read data from the bucket and do some post operations, but looks like my lambda is not getting triggered at all.
Here is my code.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket123" {
    bucket = "myawsptest25"
    acl    = "private"
    tags = {
    Name        = "My bucket1"
    Environment = "Dev"
 }
}


# Upload an object
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket123.id
  key    = "sample.txt"
  acl    = "private"
  source = "/home/ec2-user/terraform/sample.txt"
  etag = filemd5("/home/ec2-user/terraform/sample.txt")

}

# create role
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda1" {
  name = "iam_for_lambda1"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode(
    {
      "Version" : "2012-10-17"
      "Statement" : [
        {
          "Action" : "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Principal" : {
            "Service" : "lambda.amazonaws.com"

          },
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Sid" : ""
        }
      ]
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name        = "policy-2"
  path        = "/"
  description = "My test policy"

  policy = jsonencode({
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Action" : [
          "logs:*"
        ],
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Resource" : "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
      },
      {
        "Action" : [
          "s3:*"
        ],
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Resource" : "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      }
    ],
    "Version" : "2012-10-17"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda1.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.policy.arn
}

data "archive_file" "lambda_archive" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/example.py"
  output_path = "${path.module}/example.zip"
}


resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  filename      = "${path.module}/example.zip"
  function_name = "example"
  role          = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda1.arn
  handler       = "example.lambda_handler"
  runtime       = "python3.9"
}



resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "aws-lambda-trigger" {
    bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket123.id}"
    lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda_function.arn}"
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    }
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "test" {
    statement_id  = "AllowS3Invoke"
    action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda_function.function_name}"
    principal = "s3.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn = "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.bucket123.id}"
}

output "arn" {
value = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda_function.arn}"
}
```

I tried so many times but lambda is not getting invoked at all(there is no cloudwatch log group/logs created).
Can someone please help me here.

Comment: Is your system meant to trigger the AWS Lambda function when an object is uploaded to the S3 bucket? If so, you can verify this configuration by looking at the Lambda function and verifying that the Trigger is configured. Then, you can test it by uploading an object to the bucket and confirming whether the Lambda function is invoked -- look at the Monitoring tab to see if any metrics are recorded for the function. It _will_ work if configured correctly so you just need to figure out what's not correctly setup.

Comment: The trigger is configured with lambda, but when I look at the monitoring tab the metrics shows no invocation data and cloud watch does not record any logs either. But when I test the lambda manually via aws console it works

Comment: "modified some variable names" - what exactly did you modify? And how?

Comment: Did you test it by uploading an object to the S3 bucket and seeing whether the Lambda function is invoked? If that does not trigger the Lambda function, look closely at the configuration of the Trigger in the console and try to follow the logic. (That is, try and figure things out by looking at what has been deployed, rather than looking at the Terraform template.)

Comment: Manually uploading a file also doesn’t trigger lambda either, I am not sure how to resolve it as configuration looks correct

Comment: Without adding a `depends_on` argument to the `aws_s3_bucket_object` in your Terraform, referencing the `aws_s3_bucket_notification`, there is no guarantee the Lambda function and all the other setup will exist before Terraform creates the S3 object. That said, I'm not seeing an error in your configuration otherwise, so manually uploading an S3 object should trigger this. Did you not get any logs after a manual S3 upload?